# Problems with variables sass

Tags: css, sass

i need some help try to compile variables to the main sass.  I have created a document sass with variables and i compiled this documente to the main sass: @import "../sass/helpers/_variables.scss" In this document is declared some variables like colors, fonts, etc. Well, whene i try to call some variables in other document sass (compiled to the main), SASS terminal tell me this problem :

````
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/Rafager/Desktop/Inmobiliaria web/sass/desing/_header.scss",
  "line": 50,
  "column": 22,
  "message": "Undefined variable: \"$microsoft-regular\".",
  "formatted": "Error: Undefined variable: \"$microsoft-regular\".\n        on line 50 of sass/desing/_header.scss\n        from line 9 of sass/main.scss\n>>    
     font-family: $microsoft-regular;\r\n   ---------------------^\n"
}


Note: The fonts is declared in other document called and called in the main: @import "../sass/bases/_fonts.scss" and this is the code:

@font-face {
    font-family: "Microsoft YaHei UI Regular";
    src: url("../../fonts/msyh.ttc");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Microsoft YaHei UI Bold";
    src: url("../../fonts/msyhbd.ttc");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Microsoft YaHei UI Light";
    src: url("../../fonts/msyhl.ttc");
}```



¿Could you help me please?-
````

Comment: You need to put the _variables.scss file before the import of the file where you use it. However, post more code about that.

Comment: Show us your `_header.scss`, `_fonts.scss` and `_variables.scss` files please.

Comment: SOLVEDDDD!!! Thanks, i needed put _variables.scss before!!! Thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to state what $microsoft-regular is.

In your variables set fonts with names such as:

```
$microsoft-regular: 'Microsoft YaHei UI Regular';
$microsoft-bold: 'Microsoft YaHei UI Bold';
$microsoft-light: 'Microsoft YaHei UI Light';
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot mention that this is declared in fonts.css. 
Even so it doesn't work